# Regular Expression for date extraction

Tags: pyspark, replace

I have a file that has a name: Yonder_CompetitionEntries_20210928080000, I want to extract 20210928. Basically the year, month and day.

So far I have this and it's not working. The file has an extension of csv.gz

```
date_key = """RIGHT(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(filename,'.gz',''),'.csv',''), 8)"""
```

Answer (score 1):

what about without regex?

We split on `_` and take the last element, then we parse get the first few elements of the string.

```
date_key = """substring(element_at(split(filename, '_'), -1), 1, 8)"""
```

Comment: I'm a simple being: I see an answer with a solution to a "regex" problem which doesn't use regex, I upvote it.